# 1004 Error when Exporting Excel to PDF

Tags: excel, vba, function, command

I am currently trying to save an excel document as both an .xls and a PDF with one button. It worked for a bit, but now it gives me an error message and highlights the line begining with `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat`. If I take it out it then highlights the `MsgBox` line to show an problem. I am wondering if this is caused by the fact that there are 3 commands in this function?

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String
Path1 = "FILE_PATH_IS_HERE"
Path2 = "FILE_PATH_IS_HERE"
FileName1 = Range("J7")
FileName2 = Range("G3")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path1 & FileName1 & FileName2 & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Path2 & FileName1 & FileName2, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

MsgBox "Invoice Saved As Excel Doc and PDF.", , "I Systems"
```

Thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: what error does it show you?

Comment: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. Thanks!

Comment: Is the sheet protected? What are the values of `FileName1` and `FileName2` when the error happens?

Comment: Filename2 is a number e.g. 101, it changes depending on the invoice number and Filename2 is a word. I don't think the file is protected, how do I check? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmmmm is it possible that no sheet is "active"? You could try replacing `ActiveSheet` with `Worksheets("_whatever your sheet name_")`.

Comment: Also, what version of Excel?

Comment: Excel for Mac 2011 14.3.9, That didn't seam to work! The yellow highlight has now moved to the line above where it saves it as a .xls. Thanks

Comment: I can't help with Mac OS. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

```
'Don't work
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=".\FOLDER\fileName.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Because the path is relative with .\

You must have a path which is absolute as below with **Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path**

```
'work
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path+"\FOLDER\fileName.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem and the answers above didn't work for me. After an hour of pulling my hair out, here was the source of my problem.

I was passing a cell value as part of generating the filename. I was doing this in the format of fileName:= ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & CStr(Workbooks.Cells(i,j).Value) & ".pdf". The text in the cell itself was formatted to be in two rows (i.e. "top row text" + (Alt+K) + "bottom row text"). While the string looks normal in Debug.print, MsgBox, or value previews, I am thinking that there is a hidden character which encodes the new line for the cell. I believe this hidden character causes the error when passed as part of the fileName argument. I'm guessing Excel doesn't pick it up but the OS's file name system does.

In any case, this fixed the issue for me. Best of luck, this was a frustrating one to figure out!

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 0):

Check your date settings, had a similar problem and my date settings was dd/mm/yyyy, changed to dd mm yyyy without "/" and it works. I use the date as part of filename.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem on a computer, where in Excel the PDF-Export options in the PDF-Export-Dialog were set to `PDF/A-compatible`. With this option disabled, the Export worked.
I did not find an option to change this setting with the `ExportAsFixedFormat` function in VBA.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. In my case the solution to problem was removing the **"/"** on the name of the exported file because in Windows you can't save a file with that character in the filename.